# Do site beta test when using PayPal

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I am developing a site that uses PayPal for payments.  I can test with test accounts using the sandbox.  However, I am not sure what to do with the PayPal accounts when doing a beta test.  Do I have to create individual sandbox accounts and give them out to the test participants?

Answer (score 0):

Have your participants use a test Credit Card that Paypal provides: http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

From there they should be able to test your site, and you can check if transaction go through.

Comment: Ross, the participants use their actual paypal accounts and add one of these test credit cards as a funding source?

Comment: They are not required to log-in to use a credit cared with Paypal. If you do require them to sign in, let them use one of the fake cards.